# How to fix error 'str' object has no attribute 'relative_url'

Tags: python, django, django-views, wagtail, wagtail-search

I am trying to pass some wagtail contexts to the search page of a django project. The post title appears but the image, description and other parameters do not appear in the search template. How do I pass these contexts to the search template?

This is the error I get

```
AttributeError at /search/
'str' object has no attribute 'relative_url'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=hel
Django Version: 3.1.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'str' object has no attribute 'relative_url'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Bree\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\wagtail\contrib\routable_page\templatetags\wagtailroutablepage_tags.py, line 25, in routablepageurl
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

This is the **search.view.py** code

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.search.models import Query

from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from news.models import  NewsPage, NewsCategory

def search(request):
    posts = NewsPage.objects.live().public()
    categories = NewsCategory.objects.all()

    # Search
    search_query = request.GET.get('q', None)
    if search_query:
        search_results = NewsPage.objects.live().search(search_query)

        # Log the query so Wagtail can suggest promoted results
        Query.get(search_query).add_hit()
        reversenews = list(reversed(search_results))
        # Pagination
        paginator = Paginator(reversenews, 16) #show 10 articles per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            search_results = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            search_results = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            search_results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    else:
        search_results = NewsPage.objects.none()

    # Render template
    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {
        'search_query': search_query,
        'search_results': search_results,
        'recent_posts' : posts,
        'categories' : categories
    })
```

this is the search template **search.html**

```
{% extends "news/news_index_page.html" %}

{% load static wagtailcore_tags %} 

{% load wagtailembeds_tags %}

{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% load static wagtailuserbar %}

{% load wagtailimages_tags %}
{%load static%}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% load wagtailroutablepage_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">

                <h3>Query Results FOR &nbsp;<b>"{{ search_query }}"</b></h3>
            <div class="post">
                
                    {% if search_results %}
                    <div class="row">
                    
                        {% for result in search_results %}
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6"> 
                                <div class="images">
                                    {% image result.blog_image max-770x480 as blog_img  %}
                                    <a class="images" href="{% pageurl result %}" title="images"><img  src="{{result.blog_image}}" alt="images"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <h2><a href="{% pageurl result %}" title="title">{{result.title}}</a></h2>
                                    <div class="categories">
                                        {% for cat in result.categories.all%}
                                       <a href="{% routablepageurl news_page 'category_view' cat.slug %}" style="color:white">{{cat.name}}</a>
                                        {%endfor%}
                                        <p class="date"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>{{result.date}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <p>{{result.description}}</p>
                                    <a href="{% pageurl result %}" title="read more">read more</a>
                                </div>
                           
                        {%endfor%} 
                    </div>
                    {% elif search_query %}
                    <p> No results found</p>
                        <img src="{% static '/images/not_found %}" alt="image">
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                               
                <!-- Pagination -->
                    {% if search_results.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
                    <div class="box center float-left space-30">
                        <nav class="pagination">
                            {% if search_results.has_previous %}
                            <a class="control prev" href="?page={{ search_results.previous_page_number }}" title="pre"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-left"></i>Previous</a>
                            {% endif %}
                            <ul>
                                {% for page_num in search_results.paginator.page_range %}
                                <li class="{% if page_num == search_results.number %} active{% endif %}"><a href="?page={{ page_num }}" title="1">{{ page_num }}</a></li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                            {% if search_results.has_next %}
                            <a class="control next" href="?page={{ search_results.next_page_number }}" title="next">Next<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
                            {% endif %}
                        </nav>
                        <!-- End pagination -->
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
</div>
</div>
```

This is the **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.shortcuts import render
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel, MultiFieldPanel, InlinePanel
from wagtail.snippets.edit_handlers import SnippetChooserPanel
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.core.models import Page, Orderable
from wagtail.images.edit_handlers import ImageChooserPanel
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey, ParentalManyToManyField
from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TaggedItemBase
from django.core.paginator import EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger, Paginator
from wagtailmenus.models import MenuPage

from django import forms
import datetime
from datetime import date

from streams import blocks

# Create your models here.



class NewsPageTag(TaggedItemBase):
    content_object = ParentalKey(
        'NewsPage',
        related_name='tagged_items',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )


    
class NewsIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
    
    custom_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        help_text='Overwrites the default title',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("custom_title"),
    ]
    

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding custom stuff to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        posts = NewsPage.objects.live().public()
        context["recent_posts"] = posts
        context["tech_world"] = NewsPage.objects.live().filter(categories = 2)
        context["digital_creatives"] = NewsPage.objects.live().filter(categories = 10)
        context["exclusives"] = NewsPage.objects.live().filter(categories = 4)
        context["news"] = NewsPage.objects.live().filter(categories = 1)
        context["startups"] = NewsPage.objects.live().filter(categories = 3)
        context['news_page'] = self
        context['parent'] = self.get_parent().specific
        context['categories'] = NewsCategory.objects.all()
        return context

   

    @route(r"^category/(?P<cat_slug>[-\w]*)/$", name="category_view")
    def category_view(self, request, cat_slug):

        context = self.get_context(request)

        try:
            category = NewsCategory.objects.all().get(slug=cat_slug)
        except Exception:
            category= None
        if category is None:

            pass
        catPosts = NewsPage.objects.all().filter(categories__in=[category])
        reversenews = list(reversed(catPosts))
        
        paginator = Paginator(reversenews, 6)
        page = request.GET.get("page")
        try:
            # If the page exists and the ?page=x is an int
            posts = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If the ?page=x is not an int; show the first page
            posts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


        context["posts"]= posts
        context["category"] = NewsCategory.objects.all().get(slug=cat_slug)

        return render(request, "news/cat_posts.html", context)

class NewsPage(Page):
    """Blog detail page."""
   
   
    blog_image = models.ForeignKey(
        "wagtailimages.Image",
        blank=False,
        null=True,
        related_name="+",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
    image_description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True , default=" ")


    categories = ParentalManyToManyField("news.NewsCategory", blank = True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Post date", default=datetime.datetime.today)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=NewsPageTag, blank=True)


    content = StreamField(
        [
            
            ("full_richtext", blocks.RichtextBlock())
           
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=False
    )
    description = StreamField(
        [
            
            ("full_richtext", blocks.RichtextBlock())
           
        ],
        null=True,
        blank=False
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            InlinePanel("news_authors", label="Author", min_num=1, max_num=4)
        ], heading="Author(s)"),

        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel("categories", widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
            FieldPanel('tags'),
            FieldPanel('date'),
        ]),
        ImageChooserPanel("blog_image"),
        FieldPanel('image_description'),
        StreamFieldPanel("content"),
        StreamFieldPanel("description"),
    ]

    @property
    def news_page(self):
        return self.get_parent().specific

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(NewsPage, self).get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        posts = NewsPage.objects.live().public()
        context['categories'] = NewsCategory.objects.all()
        context['news_page'] = self.news_page
        context['post'] = self
        context["recent_posts"]= NewsPage.objects.live().public()
        return context 

class NewsAuthor(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, null=True)
     email = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
     image = models.ForeignKey(
         "wagtailimages.Image",
         on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
         null = True,
         blank = False,
         related_name="+"
     )
     

     panels = [
         MultiFieldPanel([
             FieldPanel("name"),
             FieldPanel("description"),
             ImageChooserPanel("image")
         ], heading="Name & Image"),

         MultiFieldPanel([
             FieldPanel("email")
         ], heading="Links")
     ]

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
         
     

register_snippet(NewsAuthor)

class NewsCategory(models.Model):

    name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(
        verbose_name="slug",
        allow_unicode= True,
        unique=True,
        max_length=255,
        help_text="A slug to identify posts by this category"
    )

    panels=[
        FieldPanel("name"),
        FieldPanel("slug")
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'News Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'News Categories'
        ordering = ['name']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    

register_snippet(NewsCategory)
```

This is the **urls.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from wagtail.admin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.core import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.documents import urls as wagtaildocs_urls

from search import views as search_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^django-admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    url(r'^search/$', search_views.search, name='search'),

]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  Post the *entire* error message, not merely the first-line text.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Take a look at this and the subsequent topic in the docs on how to serve static and media files during development:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `news_page` variable in your template is a string, rather than a page object, as that's the only use of the `{% routablepageurl %}` tag in the code examples you have shared. <del>However, you don't show where `news_page` is defined, so I may be mistaken.</del>

I have now looked at your models file, and where you define `news_page`. You have defined `news_page` in the context of NewsIndexPage. This will be used when displaying a NewsIndexPage, using Wagtail's internal views, but this is not used when rendering the search view.

Here's the response context you are setting in your `search/views.py`:

```python
    # Render template
    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {
        'search_query': search_query,
        'search_results': search_results,
        'recent_posts' : posts,
        'categories' : categories
    })
```

Can you add `news_page` to the context there?

Comment: I tried to define it but I still got the same error . I have edited the question to show the model for the `category_view` and the `news_page`

Comment: The `images, description and date ` for the search results are not displaying either. When I comment out the `categories context` in the views, the only thing displayed is the `results.title` in the template.

Comment: The error is coming from the `routablepageurl` tag, used in the search view. To help debug this could you: provide a longer stack trace; or try removing the use of that tag in your template (replace the `<a href="{% routablepageurl news_page 'category_view' cat.slug %}` etc. line with maybe `{{ news_page }}  {{ cat.slug }}`); or print out the value of `{{ news_page }}` to rule that out?

Comment: It worked when I replaced the url with `{{ cat.slug }}` as you said. Thanks